# Potentiometer comparison of two resistance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-current, potential, electrical-resistance, potential-flow

How is the current in both cases in secondary circuit same because we have changed the resistance first it is R then X so current should change. [image]

Comment: Please improve the images or retype the text.